# eslint-plugin-react return syntax error with Render

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I would like use eslint with React and Airbnb configuration. In my package.json, i can see this packages :

- "babel-eslint": "^8.2.5",
- "eslint": "^5.0.1",
- "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.0.0",
- "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
- "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
- "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
- "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.1",
- "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",

My .eslintrc file :

```
{
"extends": [
    "airbnb-base",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/react",
    "prettier/standard",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
],
"parser": "babel-eslint",
"parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaVersion": 8,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
    "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
    "impliedStrict": true,
    "classes": true
    }
},
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jquery": true
},
"plugins": ["react", "prettier"]
}
```

And if i test to render React component, i've this syntax error.

Looks like React lint is not used ... i don't understand why i've this error.

Anyone can help me ?

[image]

Comment: Could you please show the full error message, ideally as a text and not as an image?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the rules

[jsx-uses-vars](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-uses-vars.md)
and
[jsx-uses-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-uses-react.md)

to your eslint config?

I think those should fix your problem.